# (angular2-highcharts) ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm trying to use the plugin in several ways, but when I refer to "ChartModule.forRoot (require ('highcharts'))," it throws this exception

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. 
Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'require'. Consider exporting the symbol 
(position 23:13 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in 
'.../src/app/app.module.ts'
```

Obs: my projetc is based in SmartAdmin: https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-WB0573SK0

Obs 2:  I have already tested

//Highcharts

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts'; 
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

declare var require: any;

export function highchartsFactory() {
  const highcharts = require('highcharts');
  const highChartsMore = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  const solidGauge = require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge');
  ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'),
    require('highcharts/highcharts-more'),
    require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge'));
  return highcharts;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem with:

1. Updating the typescript version
2. updating the angular-cli version
3. re-install the angular2-highcharts
4. by applying the Teclanat fix https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/176#issuecomment-293973847

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

export declare let require: any;

 export function highchartsFactory() {
      const hc = require('highcharts/highstock');
      const dd = require('highcharts/modules/exporting');
      dd(hc);

      return hc;
 }
```